# Using nginx to serve tiles

Tags: tiles, tilemill, mbtiles

I created a map in Tilemill, exported to mbtiles, and created a cache of tiles using TileStache. Until now, I have been using Apache as a reverse proxy for TileStache to serve the tiles, but I'm wondering if it would be more efficient to simply serve the cached tiles with nginx.

Since tiles are static files, and I don't plan on creating new ones very often, is there any reason *not* to serve them out of the disk cache with nginx, as opposed to using some other piece of software?

Comment: This article seems to do just this - http://www.itopen.it/2012/01/17/serving-your-map-tiles-30-times-faster/ , but I'm curious why this technique doesn't seem very common.

Comment: Depends on the tradeoff between the generation and the serving. If the content is static, serve it statically. If the tiles get generated on demand (if not in the cache), then nginx or apache is going to need some help.